# Moving stripes working with background image but not with background gradients

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

My code is working perfectly with `background-image` but I want to remove the image and use the same exact code and keep the same exact functionality while using gradients (with `background`) instead of an image.

Here is my code (snippet):

```css
.gangina {
  /*background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px);*/
  background-image: url("http://s1.directupload.net/images/130503/xo29uiim.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
}
.hezi {
  -moz-animation: hezi 4s infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: hezi 4s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: hezi 4s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: hezi 4s infinite linear;
  animation: hezi 4s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hezi {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gangina hezi"></div>
```

But I don't want to rely on image therefore I want to remove the background image and use gradients like in the code below:

```
background:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#606dbc,#606dbc 10px,#465298 10px,#465298 20px);
```

Small tweak needed here to make the animation work with `background` property and gradients.

Comment: Remember `background` is shorthand for a lot of properties...make sure you state the relevant ones in the declaration.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: As far as I remember, `repeating-linear-gradient` animation requires `background-size`. Try giving something like `background-size: 20px 20px;` (*Note:* Your gradient pattern won't remain the same and you would have to adjust it accordingly).

Comment: @davidmarko: I have added my solution as an answer. Mark it as accepted when you find time :)

Answer (score 4):

Repeating linear gradients generally require `background-size` property to be set for the animation to work properly.

For this case , you could set `background-size: 28px 100%;` and the animation would work fine (refer below snippet).

```css
.gangina {
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px);  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 28px 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
}
.hezi {
  -moz-animation: hezi 0.8s infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: hezi 0.8s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: hezi 0.8s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: hezi 0.8s infinite linear;
  animation: hezi 0.8s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -28px 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hezi {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -28px 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -28px 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -28px 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes "hezi" {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -28px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gangina hezi"></div>
```